# How can i debugging my adonis ( nodejs ) framework APIs?

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, adonis.js, dd

I'm just beginner in adonis framework in NodeJS 
but I have a good experience in laravel and lumen framework

in laravel and lumen framework APIs I use `dd()` ***dump and die***  to debugging my app

but in the AONIS framework, I don't know how to debug my API `code`.

for ***IDE*** = I'm using Microsoft visual studio ( ***VS Code*** )

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging

Comment: thanks, but it's working in **API debugging** ?

Comment: you degbug you code. And hit the API endpoint. And its APi debugging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read this : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging (from @damitj07)

#### In summary :

You need to create new lauch.json like:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/yourApp",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run-script",
                "debug"
            ],
            "port": 9229
        }
    ]
}
```

and add new script in your package.json like:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "debug": "node --nolazy --inspect-brk=9229 server.js"
  },
```