# Debugging Node.js with Adonisjs 5 typscript in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-2019, adonis.js

Does anyone know how i need to set us VS2019 to debug nodejs that uses adonisjs 5 that uses typescript. My issue is that once built the .env is not being copied to build folder. I cannot place it there as on each build all the files are deleted. Any help how to set things up. Thanks!

Comment: Did you create a asp net core angular web project under VS2019? Please check [this document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58832298/how-can-i-debugging-my-adonis-nodejs-framework-apis). Maybe change `launchSettings.json` file. Besides, please describe your issue in detailed and let us know which file, or which situation you entered under debug process.

Comment: Hi. thanks first of all. No I did not use asp net core angular web project. I created a project using the adonisjs 5 ace framework. I then open the project using VS create project from existing node.js code. I then proceed to debug (no code changes) after setting the server.js file in the build folder as the startup file. The issue is that the build file does not copy over the .env file required for the project to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more elegant solution:
Add .env in the metaFiles tag in the adonisrc.json. This will copy the .env to the build folder.

Answer (score 1):

I've gone around it by using "postbuild": "@powershell copy '.env' 'build/.env'" when debugging on windows. Not the most elegant but it works to debug node.js typescript with adonisjs 5 on Visual Studio 2019.

Would prefer  a more elegant solution.